# Array of ObjectIds will not populate without error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
var ChatSchema = new Schema({
    pin: String,
    users: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"}],
    messages: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Message'}], //<----
    active: Boolean,
});

var MessageSchema  = new Schema({
        sent: Date,
        user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
        content: String
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    pin: String,
    id: String
});
```

This function is defined for the `ChatSchema`:

```
ChatSchema.methods.addMessageForUser = function(message, userid, userpin ) {
    chat = this;
        module.exports.User.findOne({id: userid, pin: userpin}).populate('messages').exec(function(err, user) {
             message = {
                user: user,
                time: new Date(),
                message: message,
            };
            chat.messages.push(message);
            chat.save();
        });

};
```

**When I run it, I get the following error:**

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "messages"
```

If I remove `populate('messages`);` Then the error goes away, but I get another error because I try to use the messages array.

Here is the code for the models:

```
module.exports.Message = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);

module.exports.User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.Chat = mongoose.model('Chat', ChatSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've got here, you're trying to populate backwards.

If each `User` had an array of `Messages`, then this `populate` call would work.  It's a method on the mongoose `Query` object, in this case, and so it's looking for a property called `messages` on the documents in the `User` collection you're querying to pull ids from - since these aren't there, you get a weird error.

Based on what you've got here, it looks like it will work if you just remove the `populate` call.